# How to display single record in handlebars if ember data store has only one data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

This is sample data store and how to display this single data without using each in template.

[image]

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('profile');
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    console.log(model);
    console.log(model.mapBy('phone'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Just like you would display multiple records, use `{{#each model as |profile|}}`

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: uhmmm if you are always trying to get one record then you must use this.store.findRecord (and probably fix your api), else, try @Kitler solution. (if you need setupController dont forget to setup model... controller.set('model', model); )

Comment: No need to set the model, he should call super when overwriting class methods

Answer (score 0):

```
{{model.firstObject.city}}
```

**firstObject** grabs the *first*  record, so you can then put in the key after